# stack overflow error in portrait orientation tablet Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, stack-overflow

There are two activity where I am getting this error:

Both activity are using `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

**First Fragment ::**
In first `Fragment` I am dynamically `inflating` the layouts  and displaying it in UI. It is working fine in horizontal view but when I changed device's `orientation` to `portrait` it is giving me error like below::

```
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112): java.lang.StackOverflowError
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.text.BoringLayout.draw(BoringLayout.java:400)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:5265)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11177)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:10894)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2755)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11282)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1788)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:1923)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
10-13 11:03:34.580: E/AndroidRuntime(9112):     at android.v
```

First fragment inflating snippet::

```
if ( !Utils.isTablet( getActivity() ) || is7inchTablet()
            || getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT )
        {
            layoutMultipleChoiceButtons = inflater.inflate( R.layout.layout_multiple_choice_buttons_hdpi_tablet, null );
            layoutTrueFalseButtons = inflater.inflate( R.layout.layout_true_false_buttons_hdpi_tablet, null );
            layoutFillInTheBlanks = inflater.inflate( R.layout.layout_fill_in_the_blanks_hdpi_tablet, null );
        }
        else
        {
            layoutMultipleChoiceButtons = inflater.inflate( R.layout.layout_multiple_choice_buttons, null );
            layoutTrueFalseButtons = inflater.inflate( R.layout.layout_true_false_buttons, null );
            layoutFillInTheBlanks = inflater.inflate( R.layout.layout_fill_in_the_blanks, null );
            // vw = inflater.inflate( R.layout.layout_question_view, null );
        }
```

I try to remove the `inflated` view and then it is working fine in both orientation.Is it any problem during  inflating the view.

**second fragment ::**
The same as first `fragment` happening to the second `fragment`. here I am also inflating the view in `fragment` dynamically that is giving me error in orientation change to `vertical`.

```
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): java.lang.StackOverflowError
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.<init>(FinalizerReference.java:34)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.add(FinalizerReference.java:48)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.graphics.Canvas$CanvasFinalizer.<init>(Canvas.java:94)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.graphics.Canvas.<init>(Canvas.java:119)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.HardwareCanvas.<init>(HardwareCanvas.java:29)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.GLES20Canvas.<init>(GLES20Canvas.java:98)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.<init>(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:62)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.<init>(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:38)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas$1.newInstance(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:46)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas$1.newInstance(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:44)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.util.FinitePool.acquire(FinitePool.java:69)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.util.SynchronizedPool.acquire(SynchronizedPool.java:39)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.obtain(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:66)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.GLES20DisplayList.start(GLES20DisplayList.java:52)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10595)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11282)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1788)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:1923)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
10-13 10:42:56.910: E/AndroidRuntime(8089): at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
```

**NOTE :: this is happening only in samsung tablet 2.0 (android version 4.0.4) . I also checked this in nexus 7  but in that it is working fine.**

Is it because of I am inflating layouts dynamically in fragments and there is flaws in layout or is it the issue device dependable? or is it another issue that getting me this type of error?

Comment: What is Line No : 400 in `BoringLayout.java` ?

Comment: can you please post code ?

Comment: Hi, DId you find any solution for this problem ?